# In Riviera-PRO how can I return non zero exit code if any assertion failed

Tags: system-verilog, assertion

I am trying to get Riviera-PRO to return a non zero exit code if any one of my SystemVerilog assertions fails during the simulation. But I can not seem to figure out how to obtain this from the command line or a Tcl script.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the simulator's exit code with the state of the simulation (pass/fail). For all simulators I know, a non-zero exit code only means that there was a problem running the executable (compile error, out of memory, etc.) Determining whether a simulation run passed or failed is usually done by parsing the log file.